# How can I reorganize this data using point free methods

Tags: javascript, data-structures, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm trying to learn a bit about functional programming and Ramda and am using an old favorite data structure manipulation of mine to attempt some point free stuff. With few or no loops. My input data:

```
const data = [{
    timeline_map: {
        "2017-05-06": 770,
        "2017-05-07": 760,
        "2017-05-08": 1250,
    }
}, {
    timeline_map: {
        "2017-05-06": 590,
        "2017-05-07": 210,
        "2017-05-08": 300,
    }
}, {
    timeline_map: {
        "2017-05-06": 890,
        "2017-05-07": 2200,
        "2017-05-08": 1032,
    }
}]
```

Desired output:

```
[
  ["2017-05-06", 770, 590, 890, ...],
  ["2017-05-07", 760, 210, 2200, ...],
  ["2017-05-08", 1250, 300, 1032, ...]
]
```

Here is my code:

```
const condense = x => x.timeline_map
var rest = []
const pluckDate = (obj, i) => {
  return [Object.keys(obj)[i]]
}
const getValues = value => {
  data.map(function () {
    return data.timeline_map
  })
}
const result = R.compose(
  R.values,
  R.mapObjIndexed(pluckDate),
  R.map(condense)
)
console.log(result(data))
```

So far all I've got is just the dates extracted:

```
[["2017-05-06"], ["2017-05-07"], ["2017-05-08"]]
```

Which is still pretty far from the solution *and* I don't know if I've even done it in a "good" way. What would be the "functional"/"ramda"/"point free" way to solve this?

[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/zefibefene/2/edit?js,console)

Comment: `Object.entries([].concat(...data.map(i => Object.entries(i.timeline_map))).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => Object.assign({}, acc, { [k]: k in acc ? acc[k].concat(v) : [v] }), {})).map(([k, v]) => [k, ...v])` --- just for fun - a pure ES solution

Comment: I do find the ability to do this last bit -- `.map(k, v) => [k, ...v]` -- one of the nicests features of ES6

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach.  There may be a simpler one:

```
const convert = pipe(
  pluck('timeline_map'), //=> [{"2017-05-06": 770, "2017-05-07": 760, ...}, ...]
  map(toPairs),          //=> [[["2017-05-06", 770], ["2017-05-07", 760], ...], ...]
  unnest,                //=> [["2017-05-06", 770], ["2017-05-07", 760], ...]
  groupBy(head),         //=> {"2017-05-06": [["2017-05-06", 770], ["2017-05-06", 590], ...], "2017-05-07": [...], ...}
  map(map(last)),        //=> {"2017-05-06": [770, 590, 890], "2017-05-07": [760, 210, 2200], ...]
  toPairs,               //=> [["2017-05-06", [770, 590, 890]], ["2017-05-07", [760, 210, 2200]], ...]
  map(apply(prepend))    //=> [["2017-05-06", 770, 590, 890], ["2017-05-07", 760, 210, 2200], ...]
)
convert(data)
```

This involves a number of distinct steps, and I've shown the sort of data each one generates.

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%7B%22timeline_map%22%3A%20%7B%222017-05-06%22%3A%20770%2C%20%222017-05-07%22%3A%20760%2C%20%222017-05-08%22%3A%201250%7D%7D%2C%20%7B%22timeline_map%22%3A%20%7B%222017-05-06%22%3A%20590%2C%20%222017-05-07%22%3A%20210%2C%20%222017-05-08%22%3A%20300%7D%7D%2C%20%7B%22timeline_map%22%3A%20%7B%222017-05-06%22%3A%20890%2C%20%222017-05-07%22%3A%202200%2C%20%222017-05-08%22%3A%201032%7D%7D%5D%0A%0Apipe%28%0A%20%20pluck%28%27timeline_map%27%29%2C%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%5B%7B%222017-05-06%22%3A%20770%2C%20%222017-05-07%22%3A%20760%2C%20...%7D%2C%20...%5D%0A%20%20map%28toPairs%29%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%5B%5B%5B%222017-05-06%22%2C%20770%5D%2C%20%5B%222017-05-07%22%2C%20760%5D%2C%20...%5D%2C%20...%5D%0A%20%20unnest%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%5B%5B%222017-05-06%22%2C%20770%5D%2C%20%5B%222017-05-07%22%2C%20760%5D%2C%20...%5D%0A%20%20groupBy%28head%29%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%7B%222017-05-06%22%3A%20%5B%5B%222017-05-06%22%2C%20770%5D%2C%20%5B%222017-05-06%22%2C%20590%5D%2C%20...%5D%2C%20%222017-05-07%22%3A%20%5B...%5D%2C%20...%7D%0A%20%20map%28map%28last%29%29%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%7B%222017-05-06%22%3A%20%5B770%2C%20590%2C%20890%5D%2C%20%222017-05-07%22%3A%20%5B760%2C%20210%2C%202200%5D%2C%20...%5D%0A%20%20toPairs%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%5B%222017-05-06%22%2C%20%5B770%2C%20590%2C%20890%5D%5D%2C%20%5B%222017-05-07%22%2C%20%5B760%2C%20210%2C%202200%5D%5D%2C%20...%5D%0A%20%20map%28apply%28prepend%29%29%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%5B%5B%222017-05-06%22%2C%20770%2C%20590%2C%20890%5D%2C%20%5B%222017-05-07%22%2C%20760%2C%20210%2C%202200%5D%2C%20...%5D%0A%29%28data%29)**.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, I wanted to try and do it in one loop with two nested reducers. Three reasons I'd thought I'd share what I came up with:

- I think the best starting point is always to write it without worrying about style until you get the result you want, before trying to go for "point free" :)
- It's nice to see that the transformation is basically a combination of two `reduce` operations: from `{ timeline_map }` to `[entries]`, and from `[entries]` to `[[key, ...values]]`
- It shows that wanting to do everything in one loop requires you to do ugly things :D

Might be interesting to see if the two-reduce, mutating `Map` approach can also be composed into a point free Ramda function... But I wouldn't be the right person to figure that out.

```js
// from [[key, value]] to Map(key, [key, values])
const timeLineReducer = (map, [key, value]) => 
  map.set(
    key, 
    (map.get(key) || [key]).concat(value)
  );

// From [{ key: value }] to Map(key, [key, values])
const dataReducer = (map, { timeline_map }) =>
   Object
      .entries(timeline_map)
      .reduce(timeLineReducer, map);

const transformData = data => Array.from(
    data
      .reduce(dataReducer, new Map())
      .values()
  );
  
console.log(transformData(getData()))
  


// data
function getData() { return [{timeline_map:{"2017-05-06":770,"2017-05-07":760,"2017-05-08":1250}},{timeline_map:{"2017-05-06":590,"2017-05-07":210,"2017-05-08":300}},{timeline_map:{"2017-05-06":890,"2017-05-07":2200,"2017-05-08":1032}}]; }
```

**EDIT: out of curiosity, I wanted to have a go at *point free* programming. A fun puzzle, but I can't say I really appreciate the outcome.**

Never tried this before, so I'm not even sure if it *is* point free. But it works!

```js
// e.g.: [2] -> [1] -> [1, 2]
const fConcat = flip(concat);

// e.g. : [1, 3] -> [1, 2] -> [1, 2, 3]
const fConcatTail = useWith(fConcat, [tail, identity]);

// e.g.: secNil(1, null) -> true
const secNil = compose(isNil, nthArg(1));

// e.g.: fConcatTailIf([0, 1], null)   -> [0, 1]
// e.g.: fConcatTailIf([0, 2], [0, 1]) -> [0, 1, 2]
const fConcatTailIf = ifElse(
  secNil,
  clone,
  fConcatTail
);

// e.g.: ["a", 1] -> lensProp("a")
const kvpKeyLensProp = compose(lensProp, head);


// e.g.: ["a", 1] -> {}              -> { a: ["a", 1] }
// e.g.: ["a", 2] -> { a: ["a", 1] } -> { a: ["a", 1, 2]}
const handleKVP = compose(
  apply(over),                          // create over that waits for {}
  ap([kvpKeyLensProp, fConcatTailIf]),  // ap with arg.
  of                                    // wrap argument in array
);

// (kvp, map) => handleKVP(kvp)(map);
const mergeKVPWithMap = uncurryN(2, handleKVP);

// Flip because reduce is inverted ((map, kvp) => ...)
// e.g.: {} -> ["a", 1] -> { a: ["a", 1]}
const entryReducer = flip(mergeKVPWithMap);
 

// e.g.: {}              -> [ ["a", 1] ] -> { a: ["a", 1] }
// e.g.: { a: ["a", 1] } -> [ ["a", 2] ] -> { a: ["a", 1, 2] }
const timelineReducer = reduce(entryReducer);

// e.g. { timeline_map: { a: 1 } } -> [ [ "a", 1 ] ]
const entriesFromData = compose(toPairs, prop("timeline_map"));

// Decorate 2nd argument of timelineReducer with entriesFromData
const dataReducer = useWith(timelineReducer, [identity, entriesFromData]);

// Return only the values from our composed object
const transformData = compose(values, reduce(dataReducer, { }));
  
// Call our transformation with our data
transformData(getData())
  


// data
function getData() { return [{timeline_map:{"2017-05-06":770,"2017-05-07":760,"2017-05-08":1250}},{timeline_map:{"2017-05-06":590,"2017-05-07":210,"2017-05-08":300}},{timeline_map:{"2017-05-06":890,"2017-05-07":2200,"2017-05-08":1032}}]; }
```

Try it in the [**Ramda REPL!**](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?%2F%2F%20e.g.%3A%20%5B2%5D%20-%3E%20%5B1%5D%20-%3E%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%0Aconst%20fConcat%20%3D%20flip%28concat%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20e.g.%20%3A%20%5B1%2C%203%5D%20-%3E%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%20-%3E%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%0Aconst%20fConcatTail%20%3D%20useWith%28fConcat%2C%20%5Btail%2C%20identity%5D%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20e.g.%3A%20secNil%281%2C%20null%29%20-%3E%20true%0Aconst%20secNil%20%3D%20compose%28isNil%2C%20nthArg%281%29%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20e.g.%3A%20fConcatTailIf%28%5B0%2C%201%5D%2C%20null%29%20%20%20-%3E%20%5B0%2C%201%5D%0A%2F%2F%20e.g.%3A%20fConcatTailIf%28%5B0%2C%202%5D%2C%20%5B0%2C%201%5D%29%20-%3E%20%5B0%2C%201%2C%202%5D%0Aconst%20fConcatTailIf%20%3D%20ifElse%28%0A%20%20secNil%2C%0A%20%20clone%2C%0A%20%20fConcatTail%0A%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20e.g.%3A%20%5B%22a%22%2C%201%5D%20-%3E%20lensProp%28%22a%22%29%0Aconst%20kvpKeyLensProp%20%3D%20compose%28lensProp%2C%20head%29%3B%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20e.g.%3A%20%5B%22a%22%2C%201%5D%20-%3E%20%7B%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%3E%20%7B%20a%3A%20%5B%22a%22%2C%201%5D%20%7D%0A%2F%2F%20e.g.%3A%20%5B%22a%22%2C%202%5D%20-%3E%20%7B%20a%3A%20%5B%22a%22%2C%201%5D%20%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%20a%3A%20%5B%22a%22%2C%201%2C%202%5D%7D%0Aconst%20handleKVP%20%3D%20compose%28%0A%20%20apply%28over%29%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20create%20over%20that%20waits%20for%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20ap%28%5BkvpKeyLensProp%2C%20fConcatTailIf%5D%29%2C%20%20%2F%2F%20ap%20with%20arg.%0A%20%20of%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20wrap%20argument%20in%20array%0A%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20%28kvp%2C%20map%29%20%3D%3E%20handleKVP%28kvp%29%28map%29%3B%0Aconst%20mergeKVPWithMap%20%3D%20uncurryN%282%2C%20handleKVP%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Flip%20because%20reduce%20is%20inverted%20%28%28map%2C%20kvp%29%20%3D%3E%20...%29%0A%2F%2F%20e.g.%3A%20%7B%7D%20-%3E%20%5B%22a%22%2C%201%5D%20-%3E%20%7B%20a%3A%20%5B%22a%22%2C%201%5D%7D%0Aconst%20entryReducer%20%3D%20flip%28mergeKVPWithMap%29%3B%0A%20%0A%0A%2F%2F%20e.g.%3A%20%7B%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%3E%20%5B%20%5B%22a%22%2C%201%5D%20%5D%20-%3E%20%7B%20a%3A%20%5B%22a%22%2C%201%5D%20%7D%0A%2F%2F%20e.g.%3A%20%7B%20a%3A%20%5B%22a%22%2C%201%5D%20%7D%20-%3E%20%5B%20%5B%22a%22%2C%202%5D%20%5D%20-%3E%20%7B%20a%3A%20%5B%22a%22%2C%201%2C%202%5D%20%7D%0Aconst%20timelineReducer%20%3D%20reduce%28entryReducer%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20e.g.%20%7B%20timeline_map%3A%20%7B%20a%3A%201%20%7D%20%7D%20-%3E%20%5B%20%5B%20%22a%22%2C%201%20%5D%20%5D%0Aconst%20entriesFromData%20%3D%20compose%28toPairs%2C%20prop%28%22timeline_map%22%29%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Decorate%202nd%20argument%20of%20timelineReducer%20with%20entriesFromData%0Aconst%20dataReducer%20%3D%20useWith%28timelineReducer%2C%20%5Bidentity%2C%20entriesFromData%5D%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Return%20only%20the%20values%20from%20our%20composed%20object%0Aconst%20transformData%20%3D%20compose%28values%2C%20reduce%28dataReducer%2C%20%7B%20%7D%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%0A%2F%2F%20Call%20our%20transformation%20with%20our%20data%0AtransformData%28getData%28%29%29%0A%20%20%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20data%0Afunction%20getData%28%29%20%7B%20return%20%5B%7Btimeline_map%3A%7B%222017-05-06%22%3A770%2C%222017-05-07%22%3A760%2C%222017-05-08%22%3A1250%7D%7D%2C%7Btimeline_map%3A%7B%222017-05-06%22%3A590%2C%222017-05-07%22%3A210%2C%222017-05-08%22%3A300%7D%7D%2C%7Btimeline_map%3A%7B%222017-05-06%22%3A890%2C%222017-05-07%22%3A2200%2C%222017-05-08%22%3A1032%7D%7D%5D%3B%20%7D)

Answer (score 1):

For demo purpose here is another solution.

```
 const concatAll = reduce(mergeWith(concat), {});
 const wrapInArray = value => [value];
 const zipKeysWithValues = (arr) => zip(keys(arr), values(arr));

 const res1 = pipe(
  pluck('timeline_map'),
  map(map(wrapInArray)),
  concatAll,
  zipKeysWithValues,
  map(flatten),
 )(data);

 const res2 = compose(
    map(flatten), 
    zipKeysWithValues, 
    concatAll, 
    map(map(wrapInArray)), 
    pluck('timeline_map'))(data);
```

You can also use both, `pipe` and `compose`. For logging use `tap(console.log)` in between any two steps.

Comment: I don't see wrapInArray or zipKeysWithVues in the docs. What version are you using?

Comment: defined on the first three line

Comment: Oh sorry I'm on mobile and completely missed that, sorry.

Comment: Note that `zipKeysWithValues` can also be written as `lift(zip)(keys, values)`.  And `wrapInArray` is also Ramda's [`of`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#of).  But I like this better than my answer.  `concatAll` is a nice abstraction and `map(flatten)` is much cleaner than `map(apply(prepend))`

Comment: Thank you @ScottSauyet, I really appreciate that you took the time to add to my solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Fastest method with pure js

```
var data = [{
    timeline_map: {
        "2017-05-06": 770,
        "2017-05-07": 760,
        "2017-05-08": 1250,
    }
}, {
    timeline_map: {
        "2017-05-06": 590,
        "2017-05-07": 210,
        "2017-05-08": 300,
    }
}, {
    timeline_map: {
        "2017-05-06": 890,
        "2017-05-07": 2200,
        "2017-05-08": 1032,
    }
}];

var mapper = {};
var output = [];
data.forEach((_node) => {
    for (let key in _node.timeline_map) {
        if (!mapper[key]) {
            mapper[key] = [];
        }
        mapper[key].push(_node.timeline_map[key]);
    }
});
for (let key in mapper) {
    let row = [key];
    row = row.concat(mapper[key]);
    output.push(row);
}
console.log(mapper); //"{"2017-05-06":[770,590,890],"2017-05-07":[760,210,2200],"2017-05-08":[1250,300,1032]}"

console.log(output); //[["2017-05-06",770,590,890],["2017-05-07",760,210,2200],["2017-05-08",1250,300,1032]]
```